# Convertir .docx a pdf

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código creado en mi api con express, el cual toma ciertos parámetros que me llegan desde el front y me crea unos archivos de word con esta información, estoy intentando convertir estos archivos a pdf antes de llamar el metodo sendMails después de crearlos pero aun no lo logro, use la librería docx-pdf sin embargo no tuve éxito ya que esta no respeta el formato del archivo word cambiando el tamaño, justificación y demás ajustes del archivo.

```
try {
    templatePaths.forEach(template => {
      const content = fs.readFileSync(`${documents}/${template}`, 'binary')
      const zip = new PizZip(content)
      const doc = new Docxtemplater(zip, {})

      doc.setData({
        cedula,
        codigo,
        fechaNotificaFormateada,
        userNotifica,
        fechaNovedadFormateada,
        centroDeCostosAnteriorName,
        centroDeCostosNuevoName,
        cargoAnteriorName,
        cargoNuevoName,
        nombreCompleto,
        descripcionDelCargo,
        objectivoDelCargo
      })

      doc.render()
      const buff = doc.getZip().generate({ type: 'nodebuffer', compression: 'DEFLATE' })
      fs.writeFileSync(`${templatesSuccess}/${template}`, buff)

      templateUrl.push({ path: `${templatesSuccess}/${template}` })
    })

    emails.push(email)
    emails.push(centroDeCostosNuevo.correo)

    sendMail(emails, templateUrl, subject, message)
    res.status(200).send()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).send()
  }
```